# Web scraping every forum post (Python, Beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, web-scraping, pycharm, nested-loops

Hello once again fellow stack'ers. Short description.. I am web scraping some data from an automotive forum using Python and saving all data into CSV files. With some help from other stackoverflow members managed to get as far as mining through all pages for certain topic, gathering the dates, title and link for each post.

I also have a seperate script I am now sturggling with implementing (For every link found, python creates a new soup for it, scrapes through all the posts and then goes back to previous link).

Would really appreciate any other tips or advice on how to make this better as it's my first time working with python, I think it might be my nested loop logic that's messed up, but checking through multiple times seems right to me.

Heres the code snippet :

```
        link += (div.get('href'))
        savedData += "\n" + title + ", " + link
        tempSoup = make_soup('http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/' + link)
        while tempNumber < 3:
            for tempRow in tempSoup.find_all(id=re.compile("^td_post_")):
                for tempNext in tempSoup.find_all(title=re.compile("^Next Page -")):
                    tempNextPage = ""
                    tempNextPage += (tempNext.get('href'))
                post = ""
                post += tempRow.get_text(strip=True)
                postData += post + "\n"
            tempNumber += 1
            tempNewUrl = "http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/" + tempNextPage
            tempSoup = make_soup(tempNewUrl)
            print(tempNewUrl)
    tempNumber = 1
    number += 1
    print(number)
    newUrl = "http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/" + nextPage
    soup = make_soup(newUrl)
```

My main issue with it so far is that `tempSoup = make_soup('http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/' + link)`
Does not seem to create a new soup after it has done scraping all the posts for forum thread.

This is the output I'm getting :

```
 http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?s=6a2caa2b46531be10e8b1c4acb848776&t=1139532&page=2
    http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?s=6a2caa2b46531be10e8b1c4acb848776&t=1139532&page=3
    1
```

So it does seem to find the correct links for new pages and scrape them, however for next itteration it prints the new dates AND the same exact pages. There's also a reaaly weird 10-12 seconds delays after the last link is printed and only then it hops down to print number 1 and then bash out all the new dates..

But after going for the next forum threads link, it scrapes same exact data every time.

Sorry if it looks really messy, it is sort of a side project, and my first attempt at doing some useful things, so I am very new at this, any advice or tips would be much appreciated. I'm not asking you to solve the code for me, even some pointers for my possibly wrong logic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Web scraper in Python for downloading all webpages with posts of a forum and the transfer it to xml.
https://github.com/vizzerdrix55/web-scraping-vBulletin-forum
https://github.com/vizzerdrix55/web-scraping-vBulletin-forum/commit/fb8d0b70b69396c237003f7c2cdbd63d1220fdee


https://github.com/GregUK/vb3_7_scraper
vb3_7_scraper
VBulletin forum scraper using python. This has been tailored for www.s2forum.com, the spiders can easily be updated for other sites
Experimenting with python scrapey to extra forums, threads and posts from VBulletin forum pre API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after spending a little bit more time, I have managed to ALMOST crack it. It's now at the point where python finds every thread and it's link on the forum, then goes onto each link, reads all pages and continues on with next link.

This is the fixed code for it if anyone will make any use of it.

```
    link += (div.get('href'))
    savedData += "\n" + title + ", " + link
    soup3 = make_soup('http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/' + link)
    while tempNumber < 4:
        for postScrape in soup3.find_all(id=re.compile("^td_post_")):
            post = ""
            post += postScrape.get_text(strip=True)
            postData += post + "\n"
            print(post)
        for tempNext in soup3.find_all(title=re.compile("^Next Page -")):
            tempNextPage = ""
            tempNextPage += (tempNext.get('href'))
            print(tempNextPage)
        soup3 = ""
        soup3 = make_soup('http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/' + tempNextPage)
        tempNumber += 1
    tempNumber = 1
number += 1
print(number)
newUrl = "http://www.automotiveforums.com/vbulletin/" + nextPage
soup = make_soup(newUrl)
```

All I've had to do was to seperate the 2 for loops that were nested within each other, into own loops. Still not a perfect solution, but hey, it ALMOST works.

The non working bit: First 2 threads of provided link have multiple pages of posts. The following 10+ more threads Do not. I cannot figure out a way to check the `for tempNext in soup3.find_all(title=re.compile("^Next Page -")):`
value outside of loop to see if it's empty or not. Because if it does not find a next page element / href, it just uses the last one. But if I reset the value after each run, it no longer mines each page =l A solution that just created another one problem :D.

Comment: helllo dear Norbis - many thanks for this awesome piece of code - greatr: btw: what about the option to get data of a certain user of the forum - is this possible? Would be awesome

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks dear Norbis for sharing your ideas and insights and concepts

since you offer only a snippet  i just try  to provide an approach that shows how to login to a phpBB  - using payload:

```
import requests
forum = "the forum name"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password', 'redirect':'index.php', 'sid':'', 'login':'Login'}
session = requests.Session()

r = session.post(forum + "ucp.php?mode=login", headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

**but wait**: we can - instead of manipulating the website using requests,
also make use a browser automation such as mechanize offers this.
This way we don't have to manage the own session and only have a few lines of code to craft each request.

a interesting example is on GitHub https://github.com/winny-/sirsi/blob/317928f23847f4fe85e2428598fbe44c4dae2352/sirsi/sirsi.py#L74-L211